# Python Pretty Print Library

Tags: javascript, python

Is there a good library for Pretty Printing Python in javascript with the help of which I can directly put my python code in div and pretty print is using javascript.

I have googled it and found it for other languages but not able to find any good one for Python.

Please help.

Comment: Python in inherently beautiful -- no pretty printing required. Seriously, I had no luck searching either. I suppose you either do without or write you own, maybe based it on python tidy

Comment: [syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter) or [pygments](http://pygments.org/) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shCore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="shBrushPython.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<pre class='brush: python'>
#!/usr/bin/env python

def hello(txt):
    print('Hello %s!' % txt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
     SyntaxHighlighter.all()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```